# Getting textbox values Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, textbox

I have a form in my project which is very simple.
It is a textbox with a label, that's it.

But when I try to get the data from those textboxes, it returns `NULL`.

`get($id)` and `get($id)->getData()`, both return `NULL`.

It's a form without any class attached to it, just to keep it simple.
The purpose of this form is to adjust a number.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to solve this?

```
    public function makenAction()
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $orderregels = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('orderregelz')->getOrderregels();
    $overzicht = $this->createFormBuilder();

    foreach($orderregels as $value)
    {
        /*
        * getting some values from database
        */
        $overzicht->add($temp->getOrderregelD(),"text",array('label'=>$tmpcompleet));
    }
    $overzicht->add('Verzenden','submit');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($orderregels as $value)
        {
            $data[] = $overzicht->get($value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$this->getRequest()` contains all the `form` data

Comment: and how do I get the form values out of it? I guess the ParameterBag?

Comment: You got suitable answer for it, `$request->query->get("input_name");`

Comment: `$request->query->get("input_name");` does not work, when I dump the `$this->getRequest()` I can see the form values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way you get data from the request

**GET**

```
$value = $request->query->get("input_name");
```

**POST**

```
$value = $request->request->get("input_name");
```

Otherwise you can simply do:

```
$formData = $overzicht->getData();
```

and then access the values like:

```
$foo = $formData['foo'];
```

To directly access all the values of a specified form, do:

`$formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get('form');`

Comment: It returns :
`array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL }`

Comment: P.S. I currenly have only 2 objects to load, just for testing

Comment: what exactly returns that?

Comment: `$formData = $overzicht->getData();` also returns `NULL`

Comment: I dump the array in twig, the array get filled with : `$request->request->get($value);`

Comment: yes because standard method for `forms` is `POST` so you have to use `$request->request` and not `$request->query`

Comment: That's what I'm saying `$request->request->get($value);` returns `NULL`

Comment: `$overzicht->add($temp->getOrderregelD(),"text",array('label'=>$tmpcompleet));` what is `$temp` and `$tempcompleet`?

Comment: `$temp` is a object from the Doctrine database. `$tempcompleet` is a string, built up from the `$temp` object' attributes.

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->request->get('form');` returns all the values from the `form`

Comment: great. Glad you find the way

Answer (score 0):

After all, you should to bind the request to form.

```
$editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
$editForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($editForm->isValid()) {
    var_dump($editForm->getData()); die;
}
```

[doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#handling-form-submissions)